# Internet Explorer Driver not working in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Iam trying to test simple rediffmail login page by sending username and password using Chrome and Explorer in Eclipse. Till yesterday, it was working fine but suddenly same code not working in Explorer(working fine in Chrome). Getting the "Configuration Failures: 1" error.

-Windows Operating system : 7

-Internet Explorer version : 8.0

-IEDriverServer_Win32_3.0.0

My code is follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.0.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.get("https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login1']")).sendKeys("sample.3400");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("edutorignitor12345");
```

[image: During Execution]

I tried to google the issue but no solution.

NOTE: Element Locators are correct as same code is running with Chrome.

Comment: Check the Internet Explorer version and see whether it is capable with the current IE browser driver.

Comment: Your code trials, relevant _HTML_ and full error stack trace please.

Comment: Hi All, I updated my question with code.. The same code was working two days before and now its not working

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue. Turned out that the driver needed to be updated. Try that.

Comment: Now Trying with IEDriverServer_x64_3.9.0 and getting "command line server for the ie driver has encountered a problem and needs to close" pop up